# What does mocking a function mean in jest. How can I pass the test for below code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

```
function doSomething(){
 const vw = document.querySelector('.a');
 const disp = vw.scrollTop;

 if(vw>700)
 // set background color of a div to red
 }
```

How can I access the variable in jest test case and pass the branch coverage ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, with unit tests you want to isolate the smallest piece of testable code and test that.
If a function makes calls to other functions, then you mock (fake) those functions.

In your case, you certainly do not want to test if `document.querySelector()` works as advertised. You assume it does. So let's just mock that:

```
test('changes something to red when scrolltop is larger than 700', () => {
  // Let's create an element that we can test with.
  const el = document.createElement('div')
  el.scrollTop = 800

  // Let's mock querySelector to return that element no matter what.
  document.querySelector = jest.fn(() => el)

  // Run your function
  doSomething()

  // Did it work?
  expect(el.style.background).toBe('red')
})
```